# Why is my custom route being ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller called banana.rb

In routes.rb I have:

```
 resources :banana, :path => "ban_fruit" do
    get 'list'
  end
```

And in the browser, I hit http://host.com/ban_fruit/list.json

But it errors, telling me: "The action 'show' could not be found for BananaController"

I need http://host.com/ban_fruit/list.json  to work, how can I do this without renaming my controller?

Comment: try `get 'list', on: :collection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out like following:

```
get 'ban_fruit/list' =>  'banana#list'
#
# ban_fruit_list GET /ban_fruit/list(.:format)    banana#list
```

Comment: This will only work if the route is defined *before* the resource route in your routes.rb. Otherwise the resource version will take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather do:

```
get 'list', on: :collection
```

Comment: but my collection is not banana. my collection is fruit. and i have code inside the banana controller. and i need to rename the path as well.

Comment: if you want to keep this very same route, it makes sense to do it this way

Comment: solution is  'ban_fruit/list', to: 'banana#index' feel free to change

Comment: Your routing seems not logic. Why two routes for index action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your route as a collection route.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for information on member vs collection routes.

Otherwise, your URL will match the `show` action for your controller (and the action will receive `:id => 'list'` in the params).

Comment: but my collection is not banana. my collection is fruit. and i have code inside the banana controller. and i need to rename the path as well.